# How to add css files based on breakpoint in library?

Tags: 8, theming

We have the following `mytheme.breakpoints.yml` file and a simple library `mylibrary` that is added through our `mytheme`. Within the `mylibrary` there are two libraries, one that is optimized for `desktop small` and another for `mobile` breakpoints.

How would I add the `mobile` css file only for when the browser's breakpoint is less than `756px`, but load `desktop small` breakpoint when browser's breakpoint is greater than `756px`?

**mytheme.breakpoints.yml**

```
mytheme.mobile
  label: mobile
  mediaQuery: 'all and (max-width: 756px)'
  weight: 1
  multipliers:
    - 1x
mytheme.desktopSmall
  label: desktop small
  mediaQuery: 'all and (min-width: 756px)'
  weight: 1
  multipliers:
    - 1x
```

**mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
mylibrary:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/some/path/desktop-small.min.css: { /* load only for min width > 756px*/ }
      css/some/path/mobile.min.css: { /* load only for max width < 756px*/ }
```

Adding [Use Theme Breakpoints as Media Queries for Theme CSS Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2822693) for reference.

Comment: Screen size detection occurs at the browser level after loading the assets. The best approach is to add the different rules in CSS media queries

Comment: @IsmailCherri Yes, we do follow that approach where we use media queries. However,  using that approach we found that the aggregated CSS files included all the media queries even when they were not needed.

Comment: Please refer to this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#libraries-options-details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found.

#### mytheme.libraries.yml

```yaml
mylibrary:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/some/path/desktop-small.min.css: { media: "all and (min-width: 756px)" }
      css/some/path/mobile.min.css: { media: "all and (max-width: 755px)" }
```

Comment: Did I miss anything? I have create a global-styling: css and there I have added

      css/style-tab.css: { media: all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)}
      css/style-mob.css: { media: all and (max-width: 767px)}
But still able to see both the files getting loaded at both the resolution